# What does this "Image Fetcher 0" do?

Tags: java, swing

While debuging a Swing application I saw this thread appear quite offen. There is a another thread called "Image Fetcher 1" also.

Can someone please explain to me what does this thread do. Is it realated to "SwingWorker" Thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you attempt to load a media resource in Swing, the request is passed to an instance of [MediaTracker](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html).  The `MediaTracker` implementation will then allocate the loading task to one of a pool of image fetcher threads.